# cheap software iSCSI with server mirroring

Tags: hyper-v, iscsi

I am looking for free / cheap solution to create iSCSI for hyper-v cluster.

I have the free Hyper-V Server, free management tool for w8 and few of my own PowerShell scripts and everything is working great.

I want to add high availability.  I can build two (or maybe three) under $1000 systems and have all SSD / RAM storage there.

We have only a few virtual machines that will run on the cluster and few 100s that start from the server but are creating different VHDX's locally.

I want most of the data to be kept in RAM then SSD. There are great commercial solutions, but - as always - there are better ideas to spend $1500-3000 (if i want to use separate computers for speed - and not only failover - it is even more expensive).

EDIT: I am asking for software only solutions (and free if possible), can deal with hardware and actually I have servers and boxes with SSD already.

Comment: Are you asking for shared storage appliance software?

Answer (score 5):

Consider skipping iSCSI. Trying to find "free" and "cheap" iSCSI software/hardware is a recipe for disaster. Hyper-V 2012 can use SMB 3.0 file shares instead of an expensive SAN. Of course, you should probably be clustering and backing those file servers with a SAN, but if you're on a budget, just grab a server with enough disks/cache, install Server 2012, and use the built-in SMB 3.0 capabilities to have that act as shared storage for your Hyper-V hosts.

Comment: You people and your fancy SMB 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking for shared storage, which I *think* you're requesting in your question...

[NexentaStor](http://www.nexentastor.org/projects/site/wiki/CommunityEdition) is an easy option for this.

You can present block storage to your systems and there's an impressive ability to tier/cache storage by leveraging SSDs in the drive pool. System RAM is used as the first level of read cache, then SSD, then disk.

Comment: Ok, nice - what about the "with server mirroring" part?

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck - your best choice is looking for some open source (Nexenta based) ISCSI SAN that has mirroring, or getting deeply into Linus / BSD / OpenSOlaris and implementing it yourself.

There is no cheap software I Know of that does the backend of mirroring nicely, not for "cheapest".

Hardware wise the LSI HA-DAS (High Available DAS) Would be a solution for 2 machines with a central SAS store - but that definitely is not "cheapest" and has a potential bottleneck (mostly: failure of the SAS fabrid, and those cost).

Cheapest: Linux / OpenSolaris and setting up the ISCSI and mirroring itself. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.illumos.zfs/353 provides some hints how to do that - DRDB is a keyword. Sadly if you want enterprise level for that it is a LOT of work - it will cost you tremendous in time to set something up properly, including web frontends and integration into monitoring tools.

Commercial: Bad - if you don't want separate hardware it is Starwind, but that will cost you 4 digit - mid 4 digit (I am just quoeted around 5000 euro for a setup with 3 machines, mirroring each other). If you can live with separate hardware then there are a number of packets (Open-E has one) but that ALSO will cost - though less.

Cheapest just does not cover HA without a lot of manual work, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the post, TomTom. Might want to clean this one up a bit. It's a touch hard to follow with the unusual punctuation technique and the misspellings break up the flow of the post.